# Request Entity Too large in IIS7.5 - WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7.5, soapui

I have a WCF Service, which receives messages from another WCF service and logs request and response in the database. This web service is hosted in IIS7.

I am getting the following error(Raw response) when I try to invoke the my service for testing purposes via SOAPUI.

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2015 15:17:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

However, my request is not really that large, when I see the raw request in SOAPUI I see that the `content-length : 89477`

I have tried the following approaches to fix my problem which does not seem to do the job for me!

1. Increase UploadReadAheadSize using appcmd.exe to 1048576
2. Updated my binding settings in web.config to the following:

> ```
> >  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Proj" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
> >                     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
> >                     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
> >                     maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
> >                     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
> >                     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
> ```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to set the maxReceivedMessageSize and readerQuotas to larger values something like this : <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Proj" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                            maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>

Answer (score 0):

maxBufferSize and maxReceiveMessageSize are both set to 65536. Make them larger!